# Looping through a List in Java

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee

Please help me understand, the below code is showing Type mismatch: "cannot convert from element type Object to List" in the for statement. I know I'm missing something silly. Please help.

```
public void setMapPriceValue(SolrItemVO solrItemVO, ArrayList proce1) throws SolrDAOException
{
    List xcatentAttrList = (List<Xcatentattr>) proce1.get(0);

    solrItemVO.setMapPrice(-1); // setting default value

    for(List  xcatentattr : xcatentAttrList){

        if(xcatentattr.get(0) == 33)

                solrItemVO.setMapPrice(xcatentattr.get(1));

                solrItemVO.setMapPriceVal(xcatentattr.get(2));

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to type things try and keep them typed

```
List<Xcatentattr> xcatentAttrList = (List<Xcatentattr>) proce1.get(0);

solrItemVO.setMapPrice(-1); // setting default value

for(Xcatentattr  xcatentattr : xcatentAttrList){

    if(xcatentattr.get(0) == 33)

            solrItemVO.setMapPrice(xcatentattr.get(1));

            solrItemVO.setMapPriceVal(xcatentattr.get(2));

    }
}
```

then the answer might be clearer ;)

The for loop is of type Xatentattr. You are looping through the list of that type.

Take a look at this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) for more info on for-each loops

Answer (score 3):

First you are mixing generics and raw types - it would make your life easier if you only used generics:

```
List<Xcatentattr> xcatentAttrList = (List<Xcatentattr>) proce1.get(0);
```

You might also consider using the correct generic type in your method signature (I assume `proce1` is a list of list):

```
public void setMapPriceValue(SolrItemVO solrItemVO, List<List<Xcatentattr>> proce1)
```

In which case you don't need the cast any more:

```
List<Xcatentattr> xcatentAttrList = proce1.get(0);
```

Then the syntax for the enhanced for loop is `for (TypeOfObjectInYourList object : list)`, so in your case:

```
for(Xcatentattr xcatentattr : xcatentAttrList)
```

Comment: As @assylias points out you are erasing the type of the object on the first line of your function. A generic `List` is really `List<Object>` so `xcatentAttrList` cannot later be cast to a `Xcatentattr`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

- First, if you declare `List xcatentAttrList` without using generics, Java can only know that your list contains `Object`s.  So your `for` loop would have to iterate through a list of `Object`s.
- Second, the cast `(List<Xcatentattr>)proce1` implies the list contains `Xcatentattr` elements, and yet you are iterating through `List` objects.

So provided you had declared the `List` using generics (and therefore saying you are working with a list of `Xcatentattr` elements), the loop `for` would be:

```
 for (Xcatentattr xcatentattr : xcatentAttrList) {
     . . .
 }
```